# Fifth last transaction of each customer on that particular day

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by, row-number

I have a table which has information :

```
customer_id | Date | Time| Sales
```

We have multiple transactions of a customer for a given day. How can I retrieve fifth last transaction of each customer on any given day?

Comment: show us the query what have you tried

Comment: I don't have any clue what to do here. I tried using partition by but that's not working since I need to partition on customer and date.

Comment: you can use order by `time` and put `row_number` to '5' and all `where` condtions for `customer name` and `date` offcourse

Comment: Can you give some details. @POHH

Comment: Seriously. Who upvotes this stuff? To do so helps no one. Nobody needs a badge that badly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.customer_id, A.Date, A.Time, A.Sales 
FROM (SELECT A.customer_id, A.Date, A.Time, A.Sales, 
             IF(@customerId = @customerId:=A.customer_id AND @Date = @Date:=A.Date, @Id:=@ID + 1, @ID:=1) AS RowNum
      FROM tableA A, (SELECT @customerId:=0, @Date:='', @Id:=0) AS B 
      ORDER BY A.customer_id, A.Date, A.Time DESC
     ) AS A
WHERE A.RowNum = 5
```

Comment: What is the reason of downvoting an answer please specify?